# How to get selected options in a group of selects with angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a group of two selects. The first one is the name of a topic and the second one is its rate (wich can be major or important). And I can add more topics (more groups of those two selects). I'm new in angularJS and I'm trying to figure out how to get the selected options in those groups.

This is what I have:

**Controller**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.topic_rows = [{
    executive_pay_ratio: [{
        topic_cd: 't1',
        topic_name: 'topic 1'
    },
    {
        topic_cd: 't2',
        topic_name: 'topic 2'
    },
    {
        topic_cd: 't3',
        topic_name: 'topic 3'
    },
    {
        topic_cd: 't4',
        topic_name: 'topic 4'
    }],
    rate_order_interest: [{
        rate_cd: 'i',
        rate_name: 'important'
    },
    {
        rate_cd: 'm',
        rate_name: 'major'
    }]
}];

$scope.currentTopic_rows = [{
    executive_pay_ratio: [{
        topic_cd: 't1',
        topic_name: 'topic 1'
    }],
    rate_order_interest: [{
        rate_cd: 'i',
        rate_name: 'important'
    }]
}];

$scope.add_topic = function () {
    $scope.topic_rows.push({
        executive_pay_ratio: [{
            topic_cd: 't1',
            topic_name: 'topic 1'
        },
        {
            topic_cd: 't2',
            topic_name: 'topic 2'
        },
        {
            topic_cd: 't3',
            topic_name: 'topic 3'
        },
        {
            topic_cd: 't4',
            topic_name: 'topic 4'
        }],
        rate_order_interest: [{
            rate_cd: 'i',
            rate_name: 'important'
        },
        {
            rate_cd: 'm',
            rate_name: 'major'
        }]
    });
};
```

}

**View**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <fieldset ng-repeat="topic_row in topic_rows">
        <select id="select_topic_{{$index}}">
            <option ng-repeat="topic in topic_row.executive_pay_ratio" ng-model="currentTopic_rows[executive_pay_ratio]" value="{{topic.topic_cd}}">{{topic.topic_name}}</option>
        </select>
        <select id="select_topic_{{$index}}_value">
            <option ng-repeat="rate in topic_row.rate_order_interest" ng-model="currentTopic_rows.rate_order_interest" value="{{rate.rate_cd}}">{{rate.rate_name}}</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <a href="" title="Add topic" ng-click="add_topic()">Add topic</a>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/97h62/68/

Thanks.

Comment: There is something called ng-options in angular. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add e.g. `ng-model="myModel"` to your `select`s. The selected options' value cann be accessed like e.g. `$scope.myModel` in your controller.

Updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97h62/69/).